# Why is DateTime.MinValue 0001-01-01T00:00 instead of 0000-01-01T00:00?

Tags: .net, datetime, theory

Why in .NET `DateTime.MinValue` is 0001-01-01T00:00 instead of 0000-01-01T00:00? I think that 0 year should be totally valid, as `DateTime` is conceptually is still interval after some event (like the birth of Jesus).

It seems that with current `DateTime` implementation it's not possible to track some date at the same year when Jesus has born.

I know this is just a theoretical question, but it's interesting to know if there are any actual reasons, why year = 0000 is not used.

Comment: There was no "Year 0", 1AD follows 1BC.

Comment: [`DateTime.MinValue`: "00:00:00.0000000 UTC, January 1, 0001, in the Gregorian calendar](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.minvalue(v=vs.110).aspx) but also interesting: [Was Jesus born in the year 0?](http://www.webexhibits.org/calendars/year-history.html#anchor-born)

Comment: Also worth looking at http://www.timeanddate.com/calendar/julian-gregorian-switch.html which is important when dealing with dates in the past.

Comment: And this one for a more recent issue: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_year_bug

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Year zero does not exist in the traditional Proleptic Gregorian calendar. 31st December 1 BCE is followed by 1st January 1 CE.

DateTimes are represented internally as ticks since the start of the Gregorian Calendar's Common Era. You can create a DateTime with other Calendars if you wish.

> The DateTime value type represents dates and times with values ranging from 00:00:00 (midnight), January 1, 0001 Anno Domini (Common Era) through 11:59:59 P.M., December 31, 9999 A.D. (C.E.) in the Gregorian calendar.
>   Time values are measured in 100-nanosecond units called ticks, and a particular date is the number of ticks since 12:00 midnight, January 1, 0001 A.D. (C.E.) in the GregorianCalendar calendar (excluding ticks that would be added by leap seconds). For example, a ticks value of 31241376000000000L represents the date, Friday, January 01, 0100 12:00:00 midnight. A DateTime value is always expressed in the context of an explicit or default calendar. -- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime(v=vs.110).aspx

ISO 8601, however, does have a year Zero, but that refers to 1BCE in the Gregorian calendar. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Years